# How do I send text to a USB device?

Tags: usb, embedded, serial-port, angstrom

I'm trying to get the "Torobot" USB servo controller to work with Angstrom on a Beagle Board XM.

The servo controller registers as a USB device.  The device just takes simple text commands, but there is no TTY associated with it.  So I'm not sure how to send commands to it.

Can I just send data like this (assuming that 002/005 is the device):

```
$ cat file.txt >> /dev/bus/usb/002/005
```

Or do I need to associate it with the generic USB device? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: Can you post the output of the command "lsusb" when the device is connected.

Comment: @Ufoguy Please see my answer below.

Comment: By the way, the proposal angled towards this kind of questions is [Embedded Programming and Design](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/50195/embedded-programming-and-design) although still only in commitment phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally Success:

I found that the Torobot USB board could be communicated with an Arduino serial driver.  Conveniently this is available through opkg:

```
opkg install kernel-module-cdc-acm
```

When the board is plugged in, it comes up as

```
/dev/ttyACM0
```

From here you can  simply echo commands to the device.

```
echo "#8P1500T100" > /dev/ttyACM0
```

This basically says "set servo 8 to position 1500 with speed 100"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this should be doable given the information provided. Stack exchange has a site specifically for robot builders which may be a more appropriate location for this question.

EDIT: You may not have a FTDI to USB driver installed but you will need it. This will provide you with the tty interface which handles this.

I think that you'll find that this link has all of the information you need to get this going: https://pixhawk.ethz.ch/tutorials/serial_terminal . Replace any hardware references with your board.

Comment: I understand why you are suggesting the robot site, but this really has less to do with the specific device (a servo controller) and more to do with serial-usb devices in general.  For instance if I wanted to send text data to a PIC64F for adjusting a temperature control - the "robot" angle is totally removed yet the underlying problem is identical.

Comment: "Yes, this should be doable" - which part?

Comment: See my edit for more information.